# How to like a page on fanpage on facebook without a mouse

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, arduino

**BACKGROUND**
I'm doing an interactive art project for school.

**PROCESS**
For this project the last step is to go to a facebook fanpage and like the facebook page.

**ASSUMPTIONS**
I'll be using Java to open up a browser and then go to the facebook page.  However, I would like to use something like one line of script to like the facebook fanpage.

**PROBLEM**
Is there will be no mouse for this interaction.

**SOLUTIONS**
Is there a script I (or stackoverflow) can write that I may execute that will like a facebook page?

Or is there any other solution that you guys can think of?

**TOOLS/LANG. BEING USED**: ARDUINO/JAVA, HTML, JAVASCRIPT and CSS.

Comment: yes there will be a keyboard.  for the input will be controlled by java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a browser automation framework like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to load the Facebook page and simulate clicking on the Like button, but you would have to log the correct user in first. Selenium has a [Java interface](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#java) you could use.

Alternatively, if you are having it run on a single machine you control, you might have luck with doing some sort of userscript (something like [this one](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/128737)) for the Facebook site so that when they are on the correct page, it clicks the Like button automatically. Then all you would have to do is launch the page from Java in the correct browser, and the userscript would do the rest. Note: Userscripts work on Firefox with [GreaseMonkey](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=greasemonkey&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/&ei=urxqT4j4MfC0iQfy762LBg&usg=AFQjCNFSNcJkvg7X1Ip12Eo9sGqXx7SLQA) installed, and on Chrome/Chromium without any extensions.

Comment: this is sounding like the real deal.  Will this self excute once on a fan page?  if so, You win!

Comment: You can define userscripts to run only for pages matching a certain URL (which can include wildcards). You should also be able to have the script check the current status of the Like button, and click it automatically if it is present and says "Like" (or logic to that effect).

Answer (score 0):

Make an application on Facebook and use their api to interact with the page: [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/)

Alternatively, use some javascript to like the page once you navigate to it

Comment: I will use Java to go to the direct facebook page.  I was more unsure on the Javascript line and how to execute that script.

Comment: If you really want to go nuts with it you could write your own firefox plugin :p. Alternatively, your javascript could be something like: (I should mention that I don't know javascript that well) 

`v=false; 
 while(!v){
    if (document.url=='thepage'){ 
       post 'url+likepost'
       v=true;
    }
}`

Comment: There is no API which will allow liking a page - the automation idea above in GregL's question is more likely to work